# Distinct values in table panels in Kibana 3

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

Let's say I have the ff. data:

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4
john      1         val3      val4
peter     2         val3      val4
john      3         val3      val4
peter     4         val3      val4
```

If this was a relational database, I would do:

select distinct column1 from mytable;

In Kibana, how will I achieve this? 
Thank you.